# How can i export csv into 3 columns instead of 2?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have two columns i am trying to separate, first i am getting rid of anything that has Jr and II, which works, and then i want to seperate the name into a separate tab

The 2 tabs i have:
Position Number, Name

XXX-XXX-XXXX-XXX,"BLOOM, DANIEL                       ",,

Would like the Name to be separated by firstname and lastname in 2 separate columns

Output 3 separate tabs :

PositionNumber, LastName, FirstName

XXX-XXX-XXXX, BLOOM, DANIEL

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

s = open('C:\\HR employees\\Listing.csv','r').read()

chars = ('$','%','^','*','JR','II')
for c in chars:
  s = ''.join(s.split(c))
out_file = open('myfile_new.csv','w')
out_file.write(s)
out_file.close()

with open('myfile_new.csv','r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)

csvfile = open('myfile2_new.csv','w')
out_file.write
out_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I have:

```
$ cat file.csv
PositionNumber, LastName, FirstName
XXX-XXX-XXXX, "BLOOM, DANIEL"
```

You can do:

```
with open('/tmp/file.csv') as csvfile:
    r=csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in r:
        row=[e.strip().strip('"') for e in row]
        print(row)
['PositionNumber', 'LastName', 'FirstName']
['XXX-XXX-XXXX', 'BLOOM', 'DANIEL']
```

The default of csv is unquoted. Just deal with the spaces and `"` with the two `strip` statements in the list comprehension.

Comment: how do i save this to a csv file?

Comment: Open a file and an `csv.writer` and write out as you read in... Read the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) docs

Comment: that does not do what i want, Name format is still 'BLOOM, DANIEL' not 'BLOOM', 'DANIEL'